# Is there a difference between Windows-created NTFS and Gparted-created NTFS?

Tags: linux, windows, ntfs, gparted, ntfs-3g

So I'm reinstalling a whole system, which has Linux and Windows, and I'm making a "shared" NTFS partition to hold data for both.

Thing is, would affect anything if I setup the partitioning scheme from Gparted before installing Windows?

Gparted can make NTFS partitions just fine via NTFS-3G, but I don't know if the partition would be exactly as what Windows would create with its partition manager.

Say, differences in versions. I believe NTFS changed a bit between Windows XP and Windows Vista for example, what kind of NTFS does Gparted creates? Or they're all the same? Or does it varies depending on the NTFS-3G version?

Comment: Windows recognized Gparted created NTFS partitions just fine.

Comment: Of course, I'm asking if there is a functional difference. ie, "Gparted created NTFS dont support X feature that Windows 7 uses to do Y thing". Or if they're functionally equivalent.

Comment: NTFS hasn't changed since 2001 when v3.1 was introduced in Windows XP. All ntfs-3g modules in use today create v3.1 file systems (unless you have a version of linux from before 2001).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question bluntly... No, there is no difference, they are all the same, and there is no cause for concern here.

NTFS as a filesystem hasn't changed in 15 years, since v3.1 was introduced in 2001 with Windows XP.

> Although subsequent versions of Windows added new file system-related
>   features, they did not change NTFS itself.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS

NTFS-3G, Gparted, and other utilities all adhere to that standard, unless you have an ancient installation of Linux from prior to 2001, you have no cause for concern. Although the filesystem version is not lists specifically for NTFS-3G, a look at it's [features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS-3G#Features) clearly lines up with version v3.1.

Comment: no, even though Linux can recognize the partition, it might not be able to recognized new features and files structures in a NTFS partition written by newer Windows.

Answer (score 1):

They just added new features for what the OS can do with them, older system's will simply not know what to do with it and will essentially treat it as a part of the file that's simply never asked for by an application - except for the rare situation of extremely large filesystems and file-names, older computers will usually see them but be unable to rename, delete, or move some files, or possibly have trouble booting from it. Old OS's might not add the redundant Master File Tables, so a Pre-XP version of windows or an old *nix version would only use the Primary - but the File System starts out the same when it's empty of data (and running chkdsk will make the necessary backup entry copies). Just don't use windows server file data dedup on it in windows or the other OS might not read parts of some files. any other Questions?

(You can always review this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS - and if there's anything you find that you have a question/worry/concern about ask away!)

Comment: Well yeah, what kind of NTFS Gparted creates? There it says NTFS was updated up to 3.1 with Windows XP, thats the kind of NTFS Gparted creates? Or which exactly?

Comment: "what kind of NTFS does Gparted creates? Or they're all the same? Or does it varies depending on the NTFS-3G version?"

Comment: @TheStack NTFS-3G, and all modern utilities like Gparted, create v3.1 NTFS file systems, it hasn't changed for close to 15 years... it is the only only NTFS filesystem version in widespread use and it hasn't changed since Windows XP.